# Java getting method to move to front not back

Tags: java

I have an add method that inserts the latest string of text to the end of a list where I want it to insert as the first string of text. Any help is appreciated. Here is the method:

```
 public void add (Magazine mag)
  {

  MagazineNode node = new MagazineNode (mag);
  MagazineNode current;

  if (list == null)
     list = node;
  else
  {
     current = list;
     while (current.next != null)
        current = current.next;
     current.next = node;
  }
   }
```

Comment: @Code-Guru looks like linked list. :P

Comment: This looks like a method from a custom linked list class. What is the name of the reference to the first node in the list?

Comment: Can you be clearer, your english is off it seems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming I understand want you need, which might be off, I think you're wanting the following method.

```
public void add_first (Magazine mag)
{
  MagazineNode node = new MagazineNode (mag);

  // make the new first node point to the current root
  node.next=list;

  // update the root to the new first node
  list=node;
}
```

Comment: Could you give me a brief explanation of why this works? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @blankwall: sure, that's a fair question. Think of it in terms of how it looks in memory. Say you have three elements in the list:

list = a -> b -> c

Now you want to add a new element, d, at the beginning. You make d.next point to the root of the current list, a.

d.next = a -> b -> c; list = a -> b -> c

And then you set list to d.

list = d -> a -> b -> c

In the special case where the list is empty (null), everything still works out.

d.next = null; list = null

And then update the root node like you do above.

list = d

Answer (score 0):

```
public void add (Magazine mag)
{
  MagazineNode node = new MagazineNode (mag);    
  node.next = list;
  list = node;
}
```